# Unhide dock when key pressed

Tags: keyboard, dock

I am currently hiding my dock. I would like to unhide it whenever a the `fn` key is pressed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign that <kbd>fn</kbd> to show/hide dock in Keyboard shortcuts, but you will override the original `fn` key.

Or you can create a **Service in Automator** that act upon a keystroke

use [this action pack](http://automatorworld.com/archives/system-action-pack/) to act upon key and do what you want building up your workflow.

Comment: That's not going to work with the `fn` key.

Comment: nop, but you can assign other that does everything

Comment: That action pack allows you to type a keystroke, not use a keystroke to activate an automator action

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>fn</kbd> key is a modifier key that lets you use a software function key F1-F19 when held down, instead of the built-in hardware F key functions (brightness, volume, etc.)

So it's not possible to use that particular key on its own as a keyboard shortcut, just as it's not possible to use the <kbd>shift</kbd> key on its own.

The best you can do is set the shortcut to <kbd>F13</kbd> using System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts, which on my particular keyboard is just above the <kbd>fn</kbd> key…